# Lydia moving to homestead?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

Is it possible to have Lydia move into a homestead with you? I have checked the wiki, and it does not say if it is possible for her to move in with you there after you have married her.

After i built the manor in Hjaalmarch, I selected the dialog option 'I think we should move somewhere else' with Lydia , trying to get her to move into the manor with me. However, the only options were for us to move either into her home or into Breezehome.

How can i get her to live there with me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lydia is one of many followers that can qualify to become a steward. Generally getting her to change house is as simple as a dialogue option.

However, you mentioned that you had also married Lydia. This could be a bit of an issue. On Xbox it's a bit of a run-around getting her to move in.

Try getting her to move back to Breezehome, sleep next to her, then try again. Other things I have heard are that a house needs a chest for both the parent's bed, and one for each or both the childrens' beds, (if you have them).

However, for PC, console commands should fairly simply fix the issue for you.

[Here is a link](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Steward_%28Hearthfire%29) of everything you need to know.

Comment: In order to avoid problems with link rot, it helps to paraphrase relevant parts of the link content within the answer. That way if the link you provided goes down, people still have a complete answer.